# Blank images and pdfs downloaded from Dropbox

Tags: javascript, angular, dropbox-api

I have a problem when downloading files from my dropbox.
While using the type 'text/csv' I can download and view txt files.
Chaning the type to 'image/jpeg' or 'application/pdf' and download the filetype gives me blank file.

Am I on the right track here or is there another way this should be done?

main.service.ts

```
downloadFile(id) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken);
  const path = `{"path": "${id}"}`;
  headers.append('Dropbox-API-Arg', path);
  return this.http.post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download', 
  null, { headers: headers });
}
```

main.component.ts

```
downloadFileBlob(data: any, name) {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}

saveFile(id, name) {
  this.dropbox.downloadFile(id).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.downloadFileBlob(data._body, name); });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was going at this the wrong way.
Dropbox github has an example of using sharingGetSharedLinkFile, which works about the same as filesDownload.
Replace sharingGetSharedLinkFile with filesDownload and provide a file path instead of the URL.

Something like this:

```
function downloadFile() {
  var ACCESS_TOKEN = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('access- 
  token')).value;
  var SHARED_LINK = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('shared- 
  link')).value;
  var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
  dbx.filesDownload({path: SHARED_LINK})
 .then(function(data) {
  var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL((<any> data).fileBlob);
  var downloadButton = document.createElement('a');
  downloadButton.setAttribute('href', downloadUrl);
  downloadButton.setAttribute('download', data.name);
  downloadButton.setAttribute('class', 'button');
  downloadButton.innerText = 'Download: ' + data.name;
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(downloadButton);
});
}
```